# Excel VBA shell command to search Chrome

Tags: vba, shell, excel

I have the following VBA code to open Chrome and navigate to a specific page:

```
Sub ExampleSub()

  Dim chromePath As String

  chromePath = """C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""

  Shell (chromePath & " -url http:google.ca")

End Sub
```

What I can't find is the command to use the search engine to run a Google search for a string I pass it, like this:

```
Search_String = "Where to find pizza in Tibet"
Shell (chromePath & " -url " & Search_String)
```

or

```
Shell(chromePath & " -search " & Search_String)
```

or

```
Shell(chromePath & " " & Search_String)
```

I'd be running several searches, so the search criteria needs to be dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are formatting your URL string incorrectly. Please consider the following solution:

```
Sub ExampleSub()

    Dim chromePath As String
    Dim search_string As String
    search_string = "Where to find pizza in Tibet"
    search_string = Replace(search_string, " ", "+")

    chromePath = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

' Uncomment the following line and comment out previous for Windows 64 versions
' chromePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"


    Shell (chromePath & " -url http://google.ca/#q=" & search_string)

End Sub
```

If you run a search from google.com and review the resulting URL you will see that search terms are seperated by `+`. This is why I replace all white spaces for `+` and then add it to the URL. Regards,

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I didn't include the string formatting in my example, but I was doing it ;)

Comment: Then you were almost there, just needed to put it all together :). Glad I could help. Regards,